# Looking for an alternative to IN operator in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

- Table1 contains   500 000 records with the Primary Key column id
- Table2 contains 3 300 000 records with the Primary Key column id

The Table2 has **duplicates** and it is indexed on the column id.

I am trying to execute the below query

```
select 
    field1,
    field2,
    field3
from
    table2
where
    id in (select id from table2 where condition1='xx' and condition2='yy')
```

if i placed id as fixed value in IN Operator condition

likewise

```
select 
    field1,
    field2,
    field3
from
    table2
where
    id in ('id1','id2','id3','id4'......'idxx')
```

I am getting an error/warning.

I would like to know if there is any alternative to using **IN** operator for improving the query performance.

Comment: Is there a typo in your first query and one of the `table2`s should read `table1`?

Comment: First of all use correct case shift! Your text is inpolite to the readers.

Comment: Please consider using tools to avoid grammatical errors if you are not a native speaker of english. Also format the post to make it more readable.

Comment: And don't use indian words like 'lakh'

Answer (score 0):

for improve performace you could use a inner join

```
    select a.field1
          ,a.field2
          ,a.field3 
    from table1 a 
    inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id 
          and b.condition1='xx'
             and b.condition2='yy'
```

and try using a composite index on table2  (condition1, condition2, id)

Comment: yes. all the condition fields are indexed but now it took more then 25 sec.

Comment: update your question and add  your actual indexes for both the table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, taht you have a type in your first query and one of the `table2`s should actually read `table1`, you can use an `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3
       FROM table2
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM table1
                            WHERE table1.id = table2.id
                                  AND condition1='xx'
                                  AND condition2='yy');
```

`EXISTS` is true, if at least one record for the given subquery exists. As you can see, the records must match your `condition1='xx'` and `condition2='yy'` but also the `id` from `table2`. If you picture, that such a row would have also been in your subquery using the `IN` -- it would have returned that ID, amongst others, so such a record had to be in there -- and vice versa, you'll see, that it is equivalent to your `IN` statement.

Should there be no such typo as I assumed, you don't need that `IN` at all. Just push the conditions up in the main query.

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3
       FROM table2
       WHERE condition1='xx'
             AND condition2='yy';
```

The ID's in the result of the subquery, are those of the rows satisfying `condition1='xx'` and `condition2='yy'`. You get exactly these rows, when you use the conditions in the main query. So you have exactly the same set of ID's in both queries, that means you have the same result set.

To further optimize this, you could create indexes to support the queries. But to give you hints on that, you must at least provide the actual table structure, the actual queries and an explain plan.